# Backup/Remove Datastore entities to Big Query Automatically at some interval

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I am looking to stream some data into Big Query and had a question around Step 3 of Google's best practices for [Streaming data into Big Query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery). The process makes sense at a high level but I'm struggling with the implementation for step 3. (I am looking to use the datastore as my transactional data store.) For step 3 says to "reconciled data from the transactional data store and truncate the unreconciled data table.". My question is this; If my reconciled data is in the Google Datastore is there a way to automate the backup and deletion of this data without manually intervention?

I know I could achieve this recommended practice by using the [Datastore Admin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin). I could:
1) Pause all writes to the datastore
2) Backup the datastore table to Cloud Storage
3) Delete all entities in the table I just backed up. 
4) Import the backup into Big Query

Is there a way I can automate this so I don't have to do it manually at regular intervals?

> Real-time dashboards and queries
>
> In certain situations, streaming data into BigQuery enables real-time analysis over transactional data. Since streaming data comes with a possibility of duplicated data, ensure that you have a primary, transactional data store outside of BigQuery.
>
> You can take a few precautions to ensure that you'll be able to perform analysis over transactional data, and also have an up-to-the-second view of your data:
>
> 1) Create two tables with an identical schema. The first table is for the reconciled data, and the second table is for the real-time, unreconciled data.
>
> 2) On the client side, maintain a transactional data store for records.
>   Fire-and-forget insertAll() requests for these records. The insertAll() request should specify the real-time, unreconciled table as the destination table.
>
> 3) At some interval, append the reconciled data from the transactional data store and truncate the unreconciled data table.
>
> 4) For real-time dashboards and queries, you can select data from both tables. The unreconciled data table might include duplicates or dropped records.